# How to handle multiple select dropdowns in a React application with a single function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forms

I have a forms with 3 select dropdowns that filter an array based on a selected value. Rather than having an onChange handler for each of these forms I was wondering if I could use a single function too handle all of them based on a parameter.

I tried passing a string into the function but it doesn't work since it is expecting an event to be passed as a parameter.

Here is the code for the react form:

```
const UserSearchBox = ({ handleChange, handleLocationChange, handleTeamChange, handleClientChange }) => {
    return (
        <form className="user-search">
            <input className="user-input" placeholder="Search for Peeps" name="userSearch" onChange={handleChange} />

            <div>
                <select defaultValue="all" onChange={handleLocationChange}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="boston">Boston</option>
                    <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
                    <option value="tampa">Tampa</option>
                </select>

                <select defaultValue="all" onChange={handleTeamChange}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="design">Design</option>
                    <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
                    <option value="finance">Finance</option>
                </select>

                <select defaultValue="all" onChange={handleClientChange}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="company">Company1</option>
                    <option value="company2">Company2</option>
                    <option value="company3">Company3</option>
                </select>
            </div>


        </form>
    )
}
```

And this is the code for the App:

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchTerm = e.target.value;

    if(searchTerm){
      let filteredUsers = users.filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
      setUsers(filteredUsers)
    } else{
      setUsers(allUsers)
    }
  }

  const handleLocationChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchTerm = e.target.value;

    if(searchTerm !== "all"){
      let filteredUsers = allUsers.filter((x) => x.location.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
      setUsers(filteredUsers)
    } else{
      setUsers(allUsers)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Header name={loggedInUser.name} profile_photo={loggedInUser.profile_photo} />
      <UserSearchBox handleLocationChange={handleLocationChange} handleChange={handleInputChange}/>
      <Users users={users} />
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: An addendum: I am currently trying to differentiate the selects using a data attribute. I will update with a solution unless there are other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters with the event by changing the onChange to this:

```
onChange={(e) => { handleLocationChange(e, param1, param2, param3...) }}
```

Or if you dont need the event you can skip it:

```
onChange{() => { handleLocationChange(param1, param2, param3...) }}
```

That way you still get your event inside, and then you add whatever other arguments you want.

Would that help you?

Comment: Yes the first option you provided is perfect, was just trying to figure out the correct syntax and/or if it was possible. Thank you!

Comment: this case will trigger reinitializing arrow function each rerender of component

Comment: @diesel94 and that is irrelevant for 99% of cases. I had a junior that was wrapping every single function in a useCallback, because its more "optimized" and will not "reinitialize the function"... not realizing that he is completely destroying the readability of the code for an optimization that he would never get to feel, in the end slowing down the work in the project. 

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: @Darkbound sounds good! Your words make sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution, however I believe @Darkbound had a more precise method.

Add data attributes to the options:

```
<select defaultValue="all" onChange={handleSelectChange}>
                    <option data-filter-type="location" value="all">All</option>
                    <option data-filter-type="location" value="boston">Boston</option>
                    <option data-filter-type="location" value="chicago">Chicago</option>
                    <option data-filter-type="location" value="tampa">Tampa</option>
                </select>
```

Then use a switch statement:

```
if (searchTerm !== "all") {
      switch (attr) {
        case 'location':
          setUsers(users.filter((x) => x.location.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())));
          break;
        case 'team':
          console.log('term: ', searchTerm);
          
          setUsers(users.filter((x) => x.team.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())));
          break;
        case 'client':
          setUsers(users.filter((x) => x.client.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())));
          break;
        default:
          setUsers(allUsers)
      }
    } else {
      setUsers(allUsers)
    }
```